# how can I use LoginView in my own view and show in HTML templates?

Tags: python, django, registration

I want to use ready Django LoginView, but in the same time I have to use my own view for registration in same HTML template. If in urls.py file I will connect 2 views than i will connect only first. So my question is that how can use LoginView in my own view and use 2 forms with jinja?
here is my views.py file and html ;)

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        formlog = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')

        if 'signup' in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.supervalid()
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Dear {username} you have been created a new accound!')
                return redirect('main')
        elif 'login' in request.POST:
            if formlog.is_valid():
                formlog.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
                return redirect('main')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        formlog = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': form, 'formlog': formlog})
# this code is not working , but not returning any errors
```

HTML

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="log-1">
            <div class="log-0">
                <p class="logtitle">BareTalk</p>
                <form method="POST" name="login">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ formlog|crispy }}
                    <button class="log-button first" type="submit">Login</button>
                </form>
                <button class="log-button second"
                     onclick="modalwindowops.open();" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Signup  -->
    <div class="modal-overlay">
        <div class="modal-window">
            <span class="close-modal" onclick="modalwindowops.close();">&times;</span>
            <form method="POST" name="signup">
                <p>Sign Up</p>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}

                <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <h1>Welcome back Amigo!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: why are you assigning view to this variable `formlog = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')`. This should be form right?

Comment: no it is view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `if 'signup' in request.POST:` nor `elif 'login' in request.POST:` is triggered in your `index()` view because your HTML forms do not actually contain those inputs. Note that the `name` attribute is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-name) for the `<form>` element.

Instead you can add a hidden `<input>` *inside* your forms, like this:

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formlog|crispy }}
    <input type="hidden" name="login" value="true" />
    <button class="log-button first" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Also,

```py
formlog = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')
```

saves a *view* to `formlog`, not a form, so calling `formlog.is_valid()` will cause an error.

Instead of

```py
elif 'login' in request.POST:
    if formlog.is_valid():
        formlog.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
        return redirect('main')
```

you probably will only need to do

```py
elif 'login' in request.POST:
    log_view = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')
    log_view(request)
```

Calling `is_valid()`, `save()`, and doing the redirect is all done by `LoginView` already. If you want to still do the custom `message.success()` you will have to override one or more of the `LoginView` methods, but that is another topic.

#### Update:

You also need to change this line in the view: `formlog = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')` (before `return render...`) to:

```py
formlog = AuthenticationForm(request)
```

Take this line outside of the `else` block.

Also add the import for the form at the top of your `views.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
```

This change is required because the template needs the form object (which is `AuthenticationForm` for `LoginView` by default) instead of the view object. The updated view function will look like:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if 'signup' in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.supervalid()
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Dear {username} you have been created a new accound!')
                return redirect('main')
        elif 'login' in request.POST:
            log_view = auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')
            log_view(request)
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    formlog = AuthenticationForm(request)
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': form, 'formlog': formlog})
```

Note that this can be improved by providing feedback when the login credentials are invalid. As it is, this updated code only reloads a blank login form if the provided credentials don't work.

Comment: I am not seeing the login form in html

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon ah right, I missed the case for when you're just loading the page (GET, not POST). I updated the answer, it should work now. I actually tested the answer this time on my machine and it's working.

Comment: I changed POST to GET and it is still not working, please help

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon no, you shouldn't change `POST` to `GET`. I was saying that my initial answer addressed only the `if request.method == 'POST':` branch of your `index()` view code, and overlooked the `else` branch, which would be what a `GET` request will follow. So, to be clear, all that you need to do is what I put in my main answer post above.

Comment: please I am looking stupid , but can you write the views file index function, youre so nice :)

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon I updated the answer. Don't worry about letting me know if this still doesn't solve your problem.